# Does Meta-refresh require a full url

Tags: html, meta-tags

Does a meta refresh tag require a full url?

I have code that looks like this, which seems to work just fine, but when I load it in lynx text browser, it says this is bad HTML.    It seems to suggest that the full URL is required (http://mydomain.com/blah.htm).

Comment: additional comment for moderator.  There are 5 questions for meta-tags and 4 questions for meta-tag.. any way we could consolidate them?

Comment: Since there were only four, I just retagged them as meta-tags manually. For larger merge/retag requests, you can post on meta.stackoverflow.com to get the right people's attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be relocatable, generate it on-the-fly with JS.

Comment: I would, but it's located between <noscript> tags to redirect users who don't have javascript enabled.

Comment: I'm sure lynx won't like it when you generate it with JS :)

Answer (score 0):

From practice I can say it does not require full url. However it may not be specified in any HTTP version and up to the browser. FF/IE/Chrome all seem to work without a full url.